# How to bypass constructor call when creating a new class instance

Tags: javascript

I would like to create an instance of a class without invoking its constructor.

For example,

```
class Test {
    private greeting: string = "Hello";

    constructor() { 
        console.log("this should not happen"); 
    }

    foo() { 
        console.log(this.greeting + " world!"); 
    }
}

magic({greeting: "Hey"}, Test) instanceof Test // true
```

For some context, I am working on an ORM. I need this to create JavaScript objects while bypassing the constructor. This is required to create plain-old-objects without the need for factories or parameter-less constructors.

Comment: Smells heavily of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain *why* you want to do that? I suspect your approach is wrong.

Comment: It's `constructor`, not `construct`. You could just pass a Boolean argument to it, defaulted to false `constructor(doFrouFrou = false) { if (doFrouFrou) { console.log('this should happen only if doFrouFrou is true'); } }` Then `var test = new Test();` would not log anything... But it looks like you want more than that, because you want to set private variables of this new instance without needing to have an accessor for it. Now *that's* crazy talk. :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey well, you can still access private variables in TS. You just have to trick the compiler. However, if you need to do that, then most likely the class is wrong to begin with. Or you're using it wrong.

Comment: The question wasn't flagged with TypeScript, but it has the wrong syntax for ECMAScript private variables, but the code seemed like pseudo code anyway... I totally agree about the XY problem.

Comment: "*This is required to create plain-old-objects*" but at the same time you want them to be an instance of a class? They aren't plain in that case. The explanation is contradictory.

Comment: I am referring to the plain-old pattern where an object is treated as "plain", aka without containing any, logic during an operation like creation and otherwise operates as expected.

In the case of persistence, the creation of an object/entity is simplified both for the user and the framework if the logic of the object is disabled.

Comment: Plain objects are those with no logic to them. They are just a collection of values. Your result (the *created*) object is not that - it's an instance of a class and also has methods. And as your answer shows, apparently also getters. Had you said that you need to create an object *from* a plain object, then it'd be more accurate because it seems you want to consume that and produce something different. But you said you wanted to *create* a plain object. That means the result should be plain. And that's contradictory because you also show a non-plain result.

Comment: what if you only wanted to use an object classes show() method and not create any new object., records ? I am basically doing: myarray.forEach(x=>{ list = new myObject(parms) ,   and afterwards show it via .show() but no object is left over from my loop ?

Comment: @Edgy if you want to use a class but not use a class then you're doing it wrong. Still, you can call a method as a function and pass in the `this` value to be used `SomeClass.prototype.someMethod.call(valueOfThis, other, parameters, here)`. However, I still want to stress that it is ***not*** normal to want a method off a class without an instance. Likely that method should have been a function to begin with. And/or the OO model you have is a broken metaphor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "`magic`" you are looking for is probably the [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) function:

```
let t = Object.create(Test.prototype, {
    greeting: {
        value: "Hey",
        writable: true
    },
});
```

By the way, as pointed out in the comments, I do not think you should skip the constructor. If you really need to, at least tell us the real problem you have.

Comment: OP made the reason clear already: writing an ORM. It's a problem I have also run into, where the user is allowed to extend a base model class and provide their own constructor for convenience. When the ORM retrieves and denormalizes objects from the db, this constructor should not be run, as it may throw, and the signature is not known by the ORM in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Object.setPrototypeOf will do most of the work.

```
const rawObject = {greeting: 'Hey'};
const testInstance = Object.setPrototypeOf(rawObject, Test.prototype);
```

However, note that this approach will override any getter/setter methods. Use this to provide the underlying value instead.

For example,

```
class Test {
    _greeting;
    
    get greeting() {
        return this._greeting;
    }
}

const a = Object.setPrototypeOf({greeting: 'Hey'}, Test.prototype);
console.log(a.greeting); // Hey
a._greeting = 'Hello';
console.log(a.greeting); // Hey

const b = Object.setPrototypeOf({_greeting: 'Hey'}, Test.prototype);
console.log(b.greeting); // Hey
b._greeting = 'Hello';
console.log(b.greeting); // Hello
```

Comment: Objects with getters are also not plain... Also, this is not a very scalable approach. You need to know internal logic of the object you create in order to create it. That code belongs as part of the object itself - either as a constructor or a factory method. Otherwise, your code is tightly coupled and thus brittle to change.

Comment: That's what I am asking, how to create an object without any knowledge of its creation logic (constructor). I am not asking whether it's a good idea.

Comment: Then the generic answer is "no". Because you cannot know whether it has getters or setters or what logic they use. Not *easily*.  Only very simple objects can be created and even then you need to know what the object definition is, in order to create them. If you have no control over the class (thus you cannot add a factory method), the correct solution is to create your own separate factory that maintains a list of creators. Yet, your question also restricts that from being an option without adequate explanation.